# angularjs select default value using ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

1st question:

How do I set default value using ng-option when my data is not an array? it's easy if the item is array, I simply can do

```
select = $scope.items[0];
```

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/nukeqodexo/edit?html,js,output)**

2nd question:

```
  <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="name for (name, value) in items"></select>
```

I actually don't know how this work ^

and in my controller I have key-value object like this

```
 $scope.items = {
    'one': 30,
    'two': 27,
    'three': 50,
    'four': 15,
    'five': 27,
    'six': 30
   };
```

Comment: ng-option when my data is not an array? but what?? and `ng-option` will work only for array

Comment: what you want to show as selected ?

Comment: @Vineet the first value of my object

Comment: @SyamPillai sorry you're wrong https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/08/11/a-brief-walk-through-of-the-ng-options-in-angularjs/

Comment: is your dropdown correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for

**Question 1:**

If `$scope.items` is not an array but an `object`
then

```
select = $scope.items.one; // to select first
```

OR

```
select = $scope.items['one']; // to select first
```

**Question 2:**

in your code

```
 <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="name for (name, value) in items"></select>
```

and in **JS**

```
$scope.secleted = $scope.items['one']
```

`(name, value) in items` will return an array of name and values (array of `key` `value` pairs). You can map the `values` with the `name`. That's why it's working

Comment: any more reading in `for in`? is it like the normal `for in` in js?

Comment: what if I have nested objects of arrays? will ng-option still work?

Comment: Actually select will work on option's value. In your case you're having two options with the same value `one` and `six`. Plus syam you forgot to set default option on controller's variable ie `selected`. update your code with `$scope.secleted = $scope.items['one']`. In your case passing this `$scope.items['one'` will not work as expected.

Comment: Instead of **for in** you can use `<select>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in items" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
</select>`

Answer (score 0):

When the values in the object are primitive types (as in your case), angular compares by value rather than reference. So:

```
$scope.selected = 30;
```

or:

```
$scope.selected = $scope.items['one'];
```

works.

If the values are non-primitive then I suggest using "track by" to track by something else than object equality.